# Inrush Current problem?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, buck, inrush-current

I have a 360W 36V Switch Mode PSU which I am using in a garden lighting system I have designed. I'm in the UK so it's running off 240V therefore can supply about 10A.

Each section of the installation (there are 6) has a Buck Converter connected to the DC side which drops the 36V DC down to 16VDC required for the LED drivers.

The Buck Converters I'm using are the XL4015 model, there are numerous sellers on the Internet:
https://www.ebay.co.uk/i/293073520634?chn=ps

The issue I'm having is that when I power up the Switch Mode PSU with more than say two buck converters, it won't start up (the power LED comes on dimly and it emits an unusual noise). I believe this has to to with startup current, since if I connect the Buck Converters one by one while the PSU is running, it works fine.

The lighting draws approximately 0.8A from the buck converter when fully 'on', so even with 6 of these (which is my plan) it's well within the operating limits of the SMPSU. I also recall when breadboarding I often saw a spark when connecting a buck converter, though the current draw was low once running.

Each buck converter is connected via a 2A fuse to the SMPSU. I have intentionally chosen the 'slow blow' type due to this startup peak.

In simple terms, what could I do to resolve this? My understanding of electronics is hobbyist level, I don't have much other than a basic test meter to play with! I'm looking at building a proper fuse board, so would like to incorporate some additional components into this ideally.

Would fitting an NTC thermistor (in series) between the SMPSU and each Buck Converter do the job?

[image]

Many thanks.

I have found the image below which believe shows the construction of the Buck Converter Boards. So with each added board to the SMPS I'm adding a 220uF capacitative load.

[image]

Comment: Please draw a block diagram.

Comment: Added! Sorry it's a little crude, but hopefully that helps. I get startup problems on the PSU even when no load is connected to the Buck Converters. I believe this may be due to their capacitance and the high inrush current? One or two is OK, but adding a 3rd (or more) is causing issues.

Comment: Thanks! I would go with NTC on your mains input. Nothing will happen on the DC side. If you want to save some power, there are plenty of examples online for NTC+relay bypass after a short timeout. Should be commercial ones too.

Comment: If the problem is actually the inrush current, a NTC will fix this. But do buck converters have that kind of problem? Maybe from the initial charging of the output capacitor?

Comment: I'm no expert - but what I do know is if I connect them all sequentially to the main PSU there's no issues. It struggles to 'start up' with multiple buck converters connected, even if they are supplying no load on their outputs.

Comment: You have changed the question so I need to revise my comment. Next time, please include all relevant details from the start. If you don’t trip your AC fuse and your AC-DC power supply do start but locks out/emits noise, won’t come to full voltage, then you need inrush current protection on the _DC_ side or better yet, ramp up the DC voltage slowly if possible.

Comment: Apologies, I only just found what I believe to be the schematicf for the Buck Converters.

Comment: My concern with the NTC approach is the current draw can be minimal with the lights connected to the 'output' side of the Buck Converters 'off' (they have their own control circuitty using DMX). In this case the series NTC thermistor wouldn't heat up and therefore have corresponding high resistance and therefore large voltage drop across it. I hope I have undertsood correctly. Looking at the thermistor datasheets there is a 'dead' zone at lower currents. Ramping up the voltage overall sounds like a better optionn, or maybe there's a way the buck converters could be switcched on sequentially?

Comment: Power supply selection is key here I think. Power supplies are not created equal. Some may take time to start up with high loads some may not. Some may not come on at all.

What lights are you using? 
Is 16V an absolute requirement? Why are you using a 36V supply and a SMPS for each light as opposed to using a single 16V power supply to power them all?